# How to fix kernel issue after upgrading from 18.10 to 19.04?

Tags: grub2, kernel, 19.04

After upgrading to 19.04 from 18.10 - I've started seeing an error revolving around linux-image-4.18.0-24-generic and seems to cause me from updates as well updating grub of course... Has anyone experienced this or can anyone guide me as to how to repair this issue?

After running this command `sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade` I then receive this error in the terminal:

```
"Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
(Reading database ... 238003 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing linux-image-4.18.0-24-generic (4.18.0-24.25) ...
/etc/kernel/postrm.d/initramfs-tools:
update-initramfs: Deleting /boot/initrd.img-4.18.0-24-generic
/etc/kernel/postrm.d/zz-update-grub:
Sourcing file `/etc/default/grub'
Sourcing file `/etc/default/grub.d/init-select.cfg'

Generating grub configuration file ...
using custom appearance settings
/etc/grub.d/bin/grubcfg_proxy: error while loading shared libraries: libcrypto.so.1.0.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
run-parts: /etc/kernel/postrm.d/zz-update-grub exited with return code 127
dpkg: error processing package linux-image-4.18.0-24-generic (--remove):
 installed linux-image-4.18.0-24-generic package post-removal script subprocess returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 linux-image-4.18.0-24-generic
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Also when attempting to do a partial upgrade it says that kernel isnt installed and fails out

**UPDATE:**
As requested I am posting the output of each command here

```
dpkg -S /etc/grub.d/bin/grubcfg_proxy
dpkg-query: no path found matching pattern /etc/grub.d/bin/grubcfg_proxy

ldd /etc/grub.d/bin/grubcfg_proxy
linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007ffe12df1000)
    libcrypto.so.1.0.0 => not found
    libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 (0x00007f4ed9660000)
    libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007f4ed9646000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007f4ed945b000)
    libm.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x00007f4ed930d000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f4ed9867000)


apt-cache policy grub-customizer - **grub-customizer:
  Installed: 5.1.0-1
  Candidate: 5.1.0-1
  Version table:
 * 5.1.0-1 500
        500 http://it-mirrors.evowise.com/ubuntu disco/universe amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status


which grub-customizer
/usr/bin/grub-customizer
```

**Update 2:** After moving both files as suggested here the output of
`sudo apt-get upgrade` is:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  linux-image-4.18.0-24-generic
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 8,573 kB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
(Reading database ... 237928 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing linux-image-4.18.0-24-generic (4.18.0-24.25) ...
/etc/kernel/postrm.d/initramfs-tools:
update-initramfs: Deleting /boot/initrd.img-4.18.0-24-generic
/etc/kernel/postrm.d/zz-update-grub:
Sourcing file `/etc/default/grub'
Generating grub configuration file ...
using custom appearance settings
/etc/grub.d/21_memtest86+_proxy: 3: /etc/grub.d/21_memtest86+_proxy: /etc/grub.d/bin/grubcfg_proxy: not found
Found memtest86+ image: /boot/memtest86+.elf
run-parts: /etc/kernel/postrm.d/zz-update-grub exited with return code 127
dpkg: error processing package linux-image-4.18.0-24-generic (--remove):
 installed linux-image-4.18.0-24-generic package post-removal script subprocess returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 linux-image-4.18.0-24-generic
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: Before you proceed with my answer below please add output of `dpkg -S /etc/grub.d/bin/grubcfg_proxy` (find package for problematic file), `ldd /etc/grub.d/bin/grubcfg_proxy` (list its dynamic-libraries), `which grub-customizer` (find path of related GRUB Customizer file), `apt-cache policy grub-customizer` (get version of GRUB Customizer package) to the question.

Answer (score 2):

The analysis of [source code](https://codesearch.debian.net/search?q=grubcfg_proxy&literal=1) says that `grubcfg_proxy` is related to `grub-customizer` package.

At first I can't find the reason why it is located in `/etc/grub.d/bin/grubcfg_proxy` on your system. This was actual for [old versions](https://answers.launchpad.net/grub-customizer/+faq/1355), but not for current versions.
At second it is strange that it tries to load `libcrypto.so.1.0.0`, while regular Ubuntu 19.04 has `libcrypto.so.1.1` (shipped with [`libssl1.1` package](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=disco&arch=amd64&mode=filename&searchon=contents&keywords=libcrypto.so.1)).
The third moment is that `grubcfg_proxy` file on *disco* is renamed to `grubcfg-proxy` and located in [`/usr/lib/grub-customizer/grubcfg-proxy`](https://packages.ubuntu.com/disco/amd64/grub-customizer/filelist).

So I'll suggest to move your binary file out the way with

```
sudo mv /etc/grub.d/bin/grubcfg_proxy ~/
```

then to be completely sure I'll recommend to purge current version of GRUB Customizer with

```
sudo apt-get purge grub-customizer
```

then update GRUB configuration:

```
sudo update-grub
```

and finally install upgrades:

```
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

---

If you need to use `grub-customizer` install its package from official repository with

```
sudo apt-get install grub-customizer
```

and use it as before.

Comment: After attempting your suggestion at step 3 - sudo update-grub :
Sourcing file `/etc/default/grub'
Sourcing file `/etc/default/grub.d/init-select.cfg'
Generating grub configuration file ...
using custom appearance settings
/etc/grub.d/10_linux_proxy: 3: /etc/grub.d/10_linux_proxy: /etc/grub.d/bin/grubcfg_proxy: not found

Comment: I'll suggest to move these files out the way with `sudo mv /etc/default/grub.d/init-select.cfg ~/` and `sudo mv  /etc/grub.d/10_linux_proxy ~/` . And then rerun `sudo update-grub`.

Comment: after moving both files : sudo update-grub - using custom appearance settings
/etc/grub.d/21_memtest86+_proxy: 3: /etc/grub.d/21_memtest86+_proxy: /etc/grub.d/bin/grubcfg_proxy: not found
Found memtest86+ image: /boot/memtest86+.elf

Comment: I've also added output of sudo apt-get upgrade after moving both files up above as an update.. My apologies at the clutter as I'm still getting used to proper formatting.

Comment: `sudo mv /etc/grub.d/*_proxy ~/`, then `sudo update-grub`

Answer (score 1):

I experienced the same problem with `grubcfg_proxy` not finding `libcrypto.so.1.0.0` in an expected location, during the cleanup phase of updating from ubuntu 18.04 to 19.04.

I posted my fix on the related shared library missing question here:

[Ubuntu 18.04: libcrypto.so.1.0.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1116133/ubuntu-18-04-libcrypto-so-1-0-0-cannot-open-shared-object-file-no-such-file-o/1185815#1185815)