# Cannot remove old linux-image after 22.04 upgrade

Tags: apt, upgrade, updates, dpkg, 22.04

I recently upgraded from `Ubuntu 21.10` to `22.04` and the process went smoothly without reporting any errors.

Whenever I try to run a system update `dpkg` raises the following error relating to the old `linux-image`:

```
/etc/grub.d/bin/grubcfg_proxy: error while loading shared libraries: libcrypto.so.1.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
run-parts: /etc/kernel/postrm.d/zz-update-grub exited with return code 127
dpkg: error processing package linux-image-5.13.0-39-generic (--remove):
installed linux-image-5.13.0-39-generic package post-removal script subprocess returned error exit status 1
dpkg: too many errors, stopping
Errors were encountered while processing:
linux-image-5.13.0-39-generic
Processing was halted because there were too many errors.
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

`dpkg` shows a status of `remove` and `Half`:

```
rH linux-image-5.13.0-39-generic 5.13.0-39.44 amd64 Signed kernel image generic
```

The following is in the `dpkg` log:

```
2022-04-25 11:15:54 startup packages remove
2022-04-25 11:15:54 status half-installed linux-image-5.13.0-39-generic:amd64 5.13.0-39.44
2022-04-25 11:15:54 remove linux-image-5.13.0-39-generic:amd64 5.13.0-39.44 <none>
2022-04-25 11:15:55 startup archives unpack
```

I have tried to re-install the `libssl1.0` package but I get the same error as above as `dpkg` tries to remove the old `linux-image` first. I have also tried to purge the image but it raises the same error as above too.

```
sudo apt purge  linux-image-5.13.0-39-generic
```

I cannot re-install the old image as it not installable.

```
sudo apt install --reinstall  linux-image-5.13.0-39-generic

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 linux-image-5.13.0-39-generic : Depends: linux-modules-5.13.0-39-generic but it is not installable
```

Comment: you played with grub-customizer?

Comment: Please https://askubuntu.com/questions/1168054/how-to-fix-kernel-issue-after-upgrading-from-18-10-to-19-04  repair grub first.

Comment: Thank you @nobody I did have `grub-customizer` installed and I used it to clean up grub a long time ago - it did not cause any issues. I will try to repair grub but I currently do not have `locate` installed and cannot use it to find the `libssl1.0.0` location, any suggestions? I cannot remove the `grub-customizer` package until I have fixed this.

Comment: Please see the solution(s) in my bug report: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubuntu-release-upgrader/+bug/1969353

Answer (score 2):

We need to fix the missing `libssl1.1` library manually. Please head over to the official Debian package library online and download the binary package that matches your system: https://packages.debian.org/stretch/libssl1.1

You will then need to run the following command to install `libssl1.1`:

```
sudo dpkg --install libssl1.1*.deb
```

After this the missing dependencies should be fixed and you can then clean out the `linux-image`

```
sudo apt purge <linux-image-name-to-remove>
```

Comment: That’s how I fixed is as well, I did however download it from the Ubuntu Impish repo: https://packages.ubuntu.com/impish/libssl1.1

Comment: Thank you @Batwam. It is probably better to grab the `libssl` package from the correct distro (Impish).