# Installation errors after upgrading to 22.04

Tags: grub2, package-management, kernel, dpkg, 22.04

I get the following errors after upgrading:

```
sudo apt --fix-broken install  
Reading package lists... Done  
Building dependency tree... Done  
Reading state information... Done  
Correcting dependencies... Done  
The following additional packages will be installed:  
  linux-image-unsigned-5.15.0-30-generic  
Suggested packages:  
  fdutils linux-doc | linux-source-5.15.0 linux-tools  
  linux-headers-5.15.0-30-generic linux-modules-extra-5.15.0-30-generic  
The following packages will be REMOVED:  
  linux-image-5.15.0-30-generic  
The following NEW packages will be installed:  
  linux-image-unsigned-5.15.0-30-generic  
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 1 to remove and 9 not upgraded.  
3 not fully installed or removed.  
Need to get 0 B/11.2 MB of archives.  
After this operation, 270 kB of additional disk space will be used.  
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y  
dpkg: linux-image-5.15.0-30-generic: dependency problems, but  
 removing anyway as  
 you requested:  
 linux-modules-5.15.0-30-generic depends on linux-image-5.15.0-30-generic | linu  
x-image-unsigned-5.15.0-30-generic; however:  
  Package linux-image-5.15.0-30-generic is to be removed.  
  Package linux-image-unsigned-5.15.0-30-generic is not installed.  

(Reading database ... 204003 files and directories currently  
 installed.)   
Removing linux-image-5.15.0-30-generic (5.15.0-30.31) ...  
/etc/kernel/postrm.d/initramfs-tools:  
update-initramfs: Deleting /boot/initrd.img-5.15.0-30-generic
/etc/kernel/postrm.d/zz-update-grub:  
Sourcing file `/etc/default/grub'  
Sourcing file `/etc/default/grub.d/init-select.cfg'  
Generating grub configuration file ...  
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-5.15.0-33-generic  
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-5.15.0-33-generic  
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-5.15.0-27-generic  
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-5.15.0-27-generic  
/etc/grub.d/bin/grubcfg_proxy: error while loading shared libraries: libcrypto.s  
o.1.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory  
run-parts: /etc/kernel/postrm.d/zz-update-grub exited with return code 127  
dpkg: error processing package linux-image-5.15.0-30-generic (--remove):  
 installed linux-image-5.15.0-30-generic package post-removal script subprocess   
returned error exit status 1  
dpkg: too many errors, stopping  
Errors were encountered while processing:  
 linux-image-5.15.0-30-generic  
Processing was halted because there were too many errors.  
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: Could you please include copy of text instead of screenshots in your post? Thanks. 

Comment: yeah sure added the text

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Cannot remove old linux-image after 22.04 upgrade](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1405040/cannot-remove-old-linux-image-after-22-04-upgrade)

Comment: As far as I can see, it's clearly an error that the package `linux-image-5.15.0-30-generic` is to be removed - this package should stay installed (it's the kernel image I'm currently running on 22.04).

Comment: @LorenzKeel There is no download option for libssl1.1 library in the given links. Help me out downloading libssl1.1

Comment: @ArturMeinild How to remove that package, I tried many commands removing that

Comment: No, you don't want to remove that package, and you don't want to install libssl1.1 - why would you do that?