# dpkg error removing linux-image-4.4.0-190-generic on upgraded Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: apt, 20.04, dpkg

After recent upgrades on an older machine (16.04 -> 18.04 -> 20.04), I can now no longer install anything as `apt` runs into an error trying to remove `linux-image-4.4.0-190-generic`, see below for terminal output:

```
$ sudo apt autoremove
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  linux-image-4.4.0-190-generic
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 to remove and 53 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 7.250 kB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
(Reading database ... 177055 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing linux-image-4.4.0-190-generic (4.4.0-190.220) ...
/etc/kernel/postrm.d/initramfs-tools:
update-initramfs: Deleting /boot/initrd.img-4.4.0-190-generic
/etc/kernel/postrm.d/zz-update-grub:
Sourcing file `/etc/default/grub'
Sourcing file `/etc/default/grub.d/init-select.cfg'
Generating grub configuration file ...
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-5.4.0-48-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-5.4.0-48-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-4.15.0-118-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-4.15.0-118-generic
/etc/grub.d/bin/grubcfg_proxy: error while loading shared libraries: libcrypto.so.1.0.0: cannot open 
shared object file: No such file or directory
run-parts: /etc/kernel/postrm.d/zz-update-grub exited with return code 127
dpkg: error processing package linux-image-4.4.0-190-generic (--remove):
 installed linux-image-4.4.0-190-generic package post-removal script subprocess returned error exit s
tatus 1
dpkg: too many errors, stopping
Errors were encountered while processing:
 linux-image-4.4.0-190-generic
Processing was halted because there were too many errors.
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I have run `sudo apt update` beforehand, and running `sudo apt upgrade` fails on the same error on removal before it manages to install anything.

The first error notice in the output of `sudo apt autoremove` or `sudo apt install -f` points to problems with shared library `libcrypto.so.1.0.0` from `libssl`, which I cannot install to fix it because of the exact problem I'm having.

I've also tried to go around it by using `--only-upgrade` in combination with `--reinstall libssl-dev libssl1.1`, but this doesn't prevent it from trying to remove the linux-image:

```
sudo apt --only-upgrade install --reinstall libssl-dev libssl1.1 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  linux-image-4.4.0-190-generic
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 2 reinstalled, 1 to remove and 53 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/2.900 kB of archives.
After this operation, 7.250 kB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Preconfiguring packages ...
(Reading database ... 177055 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing linux-image-4.4.0-190-generic (4.4.0-190.220) ...

[...]
```

**How do I remove this image and/or fix the underlying problem?**

Edit: added mention of `sudo apt update/upgrade`

Comment: `53 not upgraded`: don't do things in `apt` when it's "dirty".  You need to at least run `sudo apt update` and `sudo apt upgrade` to make sure that your package management/maintenance tasks are caught up.

Comment: I have run `sudo apt update` and when running `sudo apt upgrade` I also get the same problem: before trying to install 53 packages, it wants to remove the linux-image, meaning I can't upgrade. I'll add this in the question

Comment: See [here](https://askubuntu.com/q/1116133/21005)

Comment: Try to move the problematic file out the way by `sudo mv /etc/grub.d/bin/grubcfg_proxy ~/` and then resume package installation. Do you remember by who and when this file was created? Please check https://askubuntu.com/a/1168126/66509

Comment: @N0rbert I've tried, but no luck, it still errors. I don't know about the when of the file, but I'm the only one using the computer and I have changed some grub settings to enable windows dual-boot, so things may have been corrupted during distribution upgrade

Comment: Maybe purging the `grub-customizer` package will help. Also please add output of `ls -R /etc/grub.d` to the question.

Comment: @N0rbert @jarno Thanks for pointing me to grub-customizer, purging it wasn't possible (same error), but just starting it caused it to update and apparently fix the grub files by itself. `sudo apt install -f` worked perfectly afterwards! If you can post something to that effect as an answer, I can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have suspicious binaries in the `/etc/grub.d/` subdirectory, especially  the `grubcfg_proxy`.

This file is a part of the `grub-customizer` [package](https://codesearch.debian.net/search?q=grubcfg_proxy&literal=1).

So you have to try to call GRUB Customizer to fix the issue by its own.

And then resume package upgrade.

Comment: As mentioned above, purging it didn't work because of the same error, but starting it made `grub-customizer` fix the files by itself, so thanks!

Comment: Updated answer to reflect yours solution.