# Unable to install "Additional Drivers" after upgrade to Ubuntu 20.04 LTS

Tags: package-management, upgrade, 20.04, aptitude

### Summary:

I am unable to install Additional Drivers after upgrading from Ubuntu 18.04 LTS to Ubuntu 20.04 LTS. I receive the following error message:

```
Unable to install "Additional Drivers":
Error while installing package: installed linux-image-4.15.0-88-
generic package post-removal script subprocess returned
error exit status 1
```

System:  **Dell Precision 5510 Mobile Workstation**, 32GB RAM, 1TB Samsung NVMe hard drive; dual-booted with Windows 7 Pro-64

### Details:

If I try to rip out the package `linux-image-4.15.0-88-generic` manually, it fails. I am stuck. It also appears that I am unable to add/remove any other packages as well.

```
% sudo apt remove linux-image-4.15.0-88-generic
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  browser-plugin-evince g++-7 gir1.2-mutter-2 libargon2-0 libavutil55 libbasicusageenvironment1 libboost-chrono1.65.1 libboost-iostreams1.65.1
  libboost-locale1.65.1 libcapnp-0.6.1 libcdio17 libdouble-conversion1 libdrm-dev libdvdread4 libebml4v5 libfluidsynth1 libgdbm5 libgfortran4 libglade2-0
  libgmime-3.0-0 libgnome-desktop-3-17 libgspell-1-1 libgtkmm-2.4-1v5 libicu60 libip4tc0 libiptc0 libisc169 libisl19 libjson-c3 libllvm9:i386 liblwres160
  libmagickcore-6.q16-3 libmutter-2-0 libmysofa0 libnfs11 libnss-myhostname libnvidia-common-435 libnvidia-compute-435 libnvidia-compute-435:i386
  libnvidia-decode-435:i386 libnvidia-encode-435 libnvidia-ifr1-435 libnvidia-ifr1-435:i386 libperl5.26 libplacebo7 libpoppler73 libpostproc54
  libprotobuf10 libproxy-tools libqpdf21 libraw16 libresid-builder0c2a libssh2-1 libtinfo-dev libtinfo5:i386 libusageenvironment3 libvlc5 libvlccore9
  libx265-146 libx86emu1 libxcb-glx0-dev libxcb-render0-dev libxcb-sync-dev libxfixes-dev libxshmfence-dev linux-headers-4.15.0-99
  linux-modules-4.15.0-99-generic nvidia-compute-utils-435 nvidia-dkms-435 nvidia-kernel-common-435 php-cli php-common php-xml php7.4-cli php7.4-common
  php7.4-json php7.4-opcache php7.4-readline php7.4-xml python-cairo python-fasteners python-gobject-2 python-gtk2 python-lockfile python-monotonic
  python-six python3-asn1crypto python3-oauth qt4-qmake socat ubuntu-web-launchers vlc-data vlc-plugin-video-output
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  linux-image-4.15.0-88-generic linux-image-4.15.0-99-generic
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 2 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
2 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 16.8 MB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
(Reading database ... 331573 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing linux-image-4.15.0-88-generic (4.15.0-88.88) ...
/etc/kernel/postrm.d/initramfs-tools:
update-initramfs: Deleting /boot/initrd.img-4.15.0-88-generic
/etc/kernel/postrm.d/zz-update-grub:
Sourcing file `/etc/default/grub'
Sourcing file `/etc/default/grub.d/init-select.cfg'
Generating grub configuration file ...
using custom appearance settings
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-5.4.0-58-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-5.4.0-58-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-4.15.0-128-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-4.15.0-128-generic
/etc/grub.d/bin/grubcfg_proxy: error while loading shared libraries: libcrypto.so.1.0.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
run-parts: /etc/kernel/postrm.d/zz-update-grub exited with return code 127
dpkg: error processing package linux-image-4.15.0-88-generic (--remove):
 installed linux-image-4.15.0-88-generic package post-removal script subprocess returned error exit status 1
dpkg: too many errors, stopping
Errors were encountered while processing:
 linux-image-4.15.0-88-generic
Processing was halted because there were too many errors.
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

When I check the installed `linux-image` packages, I get the following:

```
% aptitude search linux-image | grep -v ^p
v  linux-image - 
c  linux-image-4.13.0-45-generic - 
i A linux-image-4.15.0-128-generic - Signed kernel image generic
c  linux-image-4.15.0-74-generic - 
c  linux-image-4.15.0-76-generic - 
Bd linux-image-4.15.0-88-generic - Signed kernel image generic
H  linux-image-4.15.0-99-generic - Signed kernel image generic
i A linux-image-5.4.0-58-generic - Signed kernel image generic
c  linux-image-extra-4.10.0-28-generic - 
c  linux-image-extra-4.10.0-42-generic - 
i A linux-image-generic - Generic Linux kernel image
v  linux-image-oem-5.6 -
```

I am stuck.  How do I rip this package out or fix what is wrong?  I haven't done any package management myself. All I did was an "upgrade" from 18.04 LTS to 20.04 LTS via the Software Update widget.

TIA.

Comment: Try the answers in here https://askubuntu.com/questions/1116133/ubuntu-18-04-libcrypto-so-1-0-0-cannot-open-shared-object-file-no-such-file-o

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED!

**Summary:**

The crypto library, libcrypto.so.1.0.0, was not in its usual place.  The command 'locate' was used to find existing copies of the binary file, "libcrypto.so.1.0.0", and then it was copied into place using "cp -p".

**Details:**

I edited my first post in this thread and highlighted in bold and red the key error message.  It turns out the problem was that a grub-related command could not find the crypto library, libcrypto.so.1.0.0.  A Google search string, "*ubuntu /etc/grub.d/bin/grubcfg_proxy: error while loading shared libraries: libcrypto.so.1.0.0 cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory*" turned up several hits.  It appears I ran straight into the same problem:  **https://answers.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+question/692335**.  The solution was actually documented by JohnK here:

https://askubuntu.com/a/1185815/1037505

In my case:

```
% **sudo locate libcrypto.so.1.0.0**
/opt/google/earth/pro/libcrypto.so.1.0.0
/snap/core/10444/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so.1.0.0
/snap/core/9066/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so.1.0.0
/snap/core18/1754/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so.1.0.0
/snap/core18/1932/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so.1.0.0
/snap/gnome-3-26-1604/100/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so.1.0.0
/snap/gnome-3-26-1604/98/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so.1.0.0
```

JohnK, in the thread to which I just linked his solution, determined that /snap/core18/... has the binary for Ubuntu 18.04.  So I copied one of those binaries to /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/:

```
% cp -p /snap/core18/1754/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so.1.0.0
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/
```

After that all package commands (e.g. apt, aptitude, dpkg) ran successfully.

I ran the following commands, which I found on this webpage (   ) to hopefully put my system's package system back in good shape:

```
% sudo dapt-get update --fix-missing
% sudo dpkg --configure -a
% sudo apt-get install -f
```