# Cannot run apt-get upgrade after upgrade to Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: apt, kernel, dpkg

Recently, I have clicked on the upgrade button to upgrade to `Ubuntu 20.04` from `18.04`. I think the upgrade didn't finish installing everything for some reason...

The system works fine but, every time I try using apt I get the following errors:

```
xyz@xyz-laptop:~$ sudo apt-get upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
The following packages will be REMOVED
  linux-image-4.15.0-154-generic
0 to upgrade, 0 to newly install, 1 to remove and 0 not to upgrade.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 8,485 kB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
(Reading database ... 211024 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing linux-image-4.15.0-154-generic (4.15.0-154.161) ...
/etc/kernel/postrm.d/initramfs-tools:
update-initramfs: Deleting /boot/initrd.img-4.15.0-154-generic
/etc/kernel/postrm.d/zz-update-grub:
Sourcing file `/etc/default/grub'
Sourcing file `/etc/default/grub.d/init-select.cfg'
Generating grub configuration file ...
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-5.4.0-84-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-5.4.0-84-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-4.15.0-156-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-4.15.0-156-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-4.15.0-112-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-4.15.0-112-generic
Found memtest86+ image: /boot/memtest86+.elf
Found memtest86+ image: /boot/memtest86+.bin
Found Windows Recovery Environment on /dev/sda3
Found Windows Recovery Environment on /dev/sda8
/etc/grub.d/bin/grubcfg_proxy: error while loading shared libraries: libcrypto.so.1.0.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
run-parts: /etc/kernel/postrm.d/zz-update-grub exited with return code 127
dpkg: error processing package linux-image-4.15.0-154-generic (--remove):
 installed linux-image-4.15.0-154-generic package post-removal script subprocess returned error exit status 1
dpkg: too many errors, stopping
Errors were encountered while processing:
 linux-image-4.15.0-154-generic
Processing was halted because there were too many errors.
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I wonder if anyone has any idea about what I can do to solve this issue as I am not sure if I have any backup?

EDIT: More details:

```
xyz@xyz-laptop:~$ dpkg -l | egrep -v '^ii|rc'
Desired=Unknown/Install/Remove/Purge/Hold
| Status=Not/Inst/Conf-files/Unpacked/halF-conf/Half-inst/trig-aWait/Trig-pend
+++-==========================================-===================================================-============-======================================================================================================
rH  linux-image-4.15.0-154-generic             4.15.0-154.161                                      amd64        Signed kernel image generic
```

Comment: please add `dpkg -l | egrep -v '^ii|rc'` to your question. To many errors sound not good.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to fix kernel issue after upgrading from 18.10 to 19.04?](https://askubuntu.com/a/1168126/66509). Did you have grub-customizer installed before?

Comment: Just finished checking `dpkg -l | egrep -v '^ii|rc'` : 

Desired=Unknown/Install/Remove/Purge/Hold
| Status=Not/Inst/Conf-files/Unpacked/halF-conf/Half-inst/trig-aWait/Trig-pend
+++-==========================================-===================================================-============-======================================================================================================
rH  linux-image-4.15.0-154-generic             4.15.0-154.161                                      amd64        Signed kernel image generic

Comment: I have seen something similar occur with Rstudio, libssl-related web development, and others. In each case it was non-Ubuntu software bolted onto an LTS that was not properly removed before the release-upgrade. Had to uninstall the non-Ubuntu software, then solve any remaining release-upgrade errors, then install a new version of the non-Ubuntu software that was properly compatible with the new release of Ubuntu.

Comment: Did you mean "Can run apt-get, but it exists with errors"? Because "cannot run apt..." is surely not the case here.

Comment: Only `sudo apt upgrade` and `sudo apt install -f` exits with errors, @mikewhatever. The other one `sudo apt update` works.

Answer (score 0):

DONE! Just finished solving the problem.

Turns out, `libcrypto.so.1.0.0` was missing.

I started searching for it with:

```
xyz@xyz-laptop:~$ sudo locate libcrypto.so.1.0.0
/snap/core/11420/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so.1.0.0
```

then after fining it I started copying it with:

```
xyz@xyz-laptop:~$ sudo cp /snap/core/11420/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so.1.0.0 /usr/lib/
```

And that's it!

I can now upgrade with `sudo apt upgrade`.

( I got the idea from here: [Ubuntu 18.04: libcrypto.so.1.0.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1116133/) )