# Problem with sudo apt autoremove

Tags: upgrade, kernel

I upgraded to 20.04 today.
During the upgrade I had an error message: "Could not install linux-image-4.15.0-142-generic".
Now I've just got the following output when doing "sudo apt autoremove":

```
jumbo@jumbo-M11AD:~$ sudo apt autoremove
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages will be REMOVED
  dconf-editor libhunspell-1.6-0 libmxml-dev libprotobuf-lite10 libqt5script5 libunique-1.0-0 libupnp6 linux-generic linux-image-4.15.0-142-generic
  linux-image-unsigned-4.15.0-140-generic
0 to upgrade, 0 to newly install, 10 to remove and 0 not to upgrade.
2 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 24.4 MB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
(Reading database ... 219622 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing linux-image-4.15.0-142-generic (4.15.0-142.146) ...
/etc/kernel/postrm.d/initramfs-tools:
update-initramfs: Deleting /boot/initrd.img-4.15.0-142-generic
/etc/kernel/postrm.d/zz-update-grub:
Sourcing file `/etc/default/grub'
Sourcing file `/etc/default/grub.d/init-select.cfg'
Generating grub configuration file ...
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-5.4.0-88-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-5.4.0-88-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-4.15.0-159-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-4.15.0-159-generic
/etc/grub.d/bin/grubcfg_proxy: error while loading shared libraries: libcrypto.so.1.0.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
run-parts: /etc/kernel/postrm.d/zz-update-grub exited with return code 127
dpkg: error processing package linux-image-4.15.0-142-generic (--remove):
 installed linux-image-4.15.0-142-generic package post-removal script subprocess returned error exit status 1
dpkg: too many errors, stopping
Errors were encountered while processing:
 linux-image-4.15.0-142-generic
Processing was halted because there were too many errors.
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
jumbo@jumbo-M11AD:~$
```

Should I be concerned, and what can be done about it?

Any advice would be gratefully received!

Edit:
NOrbet, I followed your instruction and this is the result:

```
jumbo@jumbo-M11AD:~$ sudo rm /etc/grub.d/bin/grubcfg_proxy
[sudo] password for jumbo: 
jumbo@jumbo-M11AD:~$ sudo apt-get purge grub-customizer
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  hwinfo libhd21 libx86emu2
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following packages will be REMOVED
  grub-customizer* linux-image-4.15.0-142-generic
  linux-image-unsigned-4.15.0-140-generic
0 to upgrade, 0 to newly install, 3 to remove and 0 not to upgrade.
2 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 21.0 MB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
(Reading database ... 219622 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing linux-image-4.15.0-142-generic (4.15.0-142.146) ...
/etc/kernel/postrm.d/initramfs-tools:
update-initramfs: Deleting /boot/initrd.img-4.15.0-142-generic
/etc/kernel/postrm.d/zz-update-grub:
Sourcing file `/etc/default/grub'
Sourcing file `/etc/default/grub.d/init-select.cfg'
Generating grub configuration file ...
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-5.4.0-88-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-5.4.0-88-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-4.15.0-159-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-4.15.0-159-generic
/etc/grub.d/25_custom_proxy: 3: /etc/grub.d/bin/grubcfg_proxy: not found
run-parts: /etc/kernel/postrm.d/zz-update-grub exited with return code 127
dpkg: error processing package linux-image-4.15.0-142-generic (--remove):
 installed linux-image-4.15.0-142-generic package post-removal script subprocess returned error exit status 1
dpkg: too many errors, stopping
Errors were encountered while processing:
 linux-image-4.15.0-142-generic
Processing was halted because there were too many errors.
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
jumbo@jumbo-M11AD:~$
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to fix kernel issue after upgrading from 18.10 to 19.04?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1168054/how-to-fix-kernel-issue-after-upgrading-from-18-10-to-19-04)

Comment: "Does this answer your question?" - It doesn't seem to address the same issues I am having, but perhaps it does, I don't know enough to be able to understand what you are saying, and additionally it has no accepted answer - but thanks for the link. I think as an ignoramus, that I need  it spelled out!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Ubuntu 18.04: libcrypto.so.1.0.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1116133/ubuntu-18-04-libcrypto-so-1-0-0-cannot-open-shared-object-file-no-such-file-o)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, then remove the problematic file out the way by

```
sudo rm /etc/grub.d/bin/grubcfg_proxy
sudo rm /etc/grub.d/25_custom_proxy
```

then run

```
sudo apt-get purge grub-customizer
sudo apt autoremove
```

and finally update GRUB menu by

```
sudo update-grub
```

Comment: I've amended to question to include the result of "sudo rm /etc/grub.d/bin/grubcfg_proxy" and sudo apt-get purge grub-customizer, which is as far as I got.

Comment: Run  `sudo rm /etc/grub.d/25_custom_proxy` and retry next commands.

Comment: That did it. Thank you.