# Free Download Manager is not opening in ubuntu 22.04

Tags: software-installation

I've installed free download manager in Ubuntu 22.04 lts. When I click free download manager icon it doesn't open. what is the solution of this problem?

Comment: How did you install it?

Comment: @ChanganAuto I've installed it with deb file from official website.

Comment: Can you run it from terminal and post the output? I don't know the exact command, but it may be `fdm` or `free-download-manager`.

Answer (score 1):

The error you will most likely to face when you try to open fdm on terminal through `/opt/freedownloadmanager/fdm` is:

```
error while loading shared libraries: libcrypto.so.1.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

In this case, the missing libcrypto.so.1.1 is part of libssl1.1, which needs to be installed in order to fix the issue which you have to manually install from [packages.debian.com](https://packages.debian.org/stretch/libssl1.1). Pick the architecture you want and download it. After that you should install it using (remember to put ur own file name in the command):

```
sudo dpkg -i [downloaded file's name].deb
```

Thanks a lot to @JakobWeimar with his [answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1403778/upgrading-to-ubuntu-22-04-causes-libcrypto-errors-apt-dpkg-broken)