# Where to find grub.d for ubuntu 22.04 LTS

Tags: boot, grub2, upgrade, 22.04

upgrading from 20.04 to 22.04 via 21.04,

my 20.04 had Grub Customizer that was carring its grub.d modified folder,

so now I am struggling with [Upgrading to Ubuntu 22.04 causes libcrypto errors, apt/dpkg broken](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1403778/upgrading-to-ubuntu-22-04-causes-libcrypto-errors-apt-dpkg-broken)

I am not an Ubuntu or Grub expert but think that getting the righr grub.d folder and reinstalling grub should fix the problem.

I got errors only when trying to do `sudo upgrade-grub` , but I would like to get a text like grub menu and stop the timer,

so where I should look for the right grub.d folder for Ubuntu 22.04LTs 64bit amd ?

Comment: Your grub is still /etc/grub.d. But Grub Customizer replaces all the grub scripts with proxy  files. If you can boot, just totally reinstall grub, otherwise use chroot or Boot-Repair to reinstall it or Super grub to boot. If encrypted & LVM, you may need to manually mount those.  If just a few changes often better to just edit /etc/default/grub. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MaintenanceFreeCustomGrub2Screen

Comment: thanks, but not really clear to me, does reinstalling grub replace grub.d , where I should look for ubuntu 22.04 grub.d folder ?? I mean the one that comes when doing a fresh install ?

Comment: I thought Customizer did backup the original grub files into a sub-directly of /etc/grub.d, but have never used it. If you do a total reinstall of grub it will replace the proxy files with standard grub files in /etc/grub.d.